# vb.net correct error implement System.IDisposable

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, idisposable

I am just lost with trying to correct this error
 
Error   BC36010 'Using' operand of type 'Boolean' must implement 'System.IDisposable'

The Error only shows up when I remove the If End If design from the code below and implement Using
Reason for the use of Using End Using was garbage clean up
**So the question is how to implement System.IDisposable ?**

```
Public Sub haveFILE()
    'Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Me\source\repos\TestForms\TestForms\Resource\"
    Using Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "Check.txt") Then
        tbHaveDB.Text = "File NOT Found"
        ' Create or overwrite the file.
        Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path & "Check.txt")
        fs.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is about `using`

```vb
Using Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "Check.txt") Then
End Using
```

`My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "Check.txt")` returns boolean. Just don't use `using`. Use `if then` in this case. `Using` is when you create `IDisposable` object

Your code seem confusing between different blocks. You have half `if` half using. I think, it needs to be this

```vb
if Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "Check.txt") Then
    tbHaveDB.Text = "File NOT Found"
    ' Create or overwrite the file.
else
     using fs As FileStream = File.Create(path & "Check.txt")
         ' write to stream here
         fs.Close()
     End Using
End If
```

Comment: How do I know when I am using a IDisposable Object

Comment: @Vector Any object that you can call `o.Dispose()` supposedly implements `IDisposable`. This is a common pattern in .net

Comment: Thanks Need to read about Objects that are disposable Is the Object here FileSystem or something else

Comment: @Vector you can create file at once using `File.WriteAllText` or `File.WriteAllBytes`. In most cases no need open the stream

Comment: I saw the WriteAllText but did not use it found this resource https://sodocumentation.net/vb-net/topic/3204/disposable-objects I will let you go back to ESPN working from home?

Comment: @Vector I am on a zoom meeting